# Are there ways to access files removed from intermediate layer after docker 1.10?

Tags: security, docker, dockerfile, docker-build

After docker 1.10, `docker history` no longer shows intermediate layers of an image if you pulled it from somewhere else, rather than building locally.

[This github issue](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/20316) discusses about this change, and also mentions that using `docker save` and `docker load`, you can make use of intermediate layers as caches.

Does this mean, if an image is built and is simply uploaded to a repository (i.e. no tar files), there is no way for someone who downloads the image to recover the intermediate layers?

What I specifically want to know is:

```
COPY sensitive_file .
RUN do_something_with ./sensitive_file
RUN rm ./sensitive_file
```

Is it okay to write Dockerfile like the above, and assume that (unless there is an unknown vulnerability in docker) this sensitive file will not be accessible by others?

---

I'm aware that there are other ways of handling credentials or sensitive files, such as setting up a local server and `RUN wget file && use file && rm file`, docker secret with swarm, or using docker vault. I'm not looking for different approaches to handle sensitive files; rather I am just interested if the above approach makes the file accessible or not. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image is still shipped as layers even though you don't have an image id for each layer. You can see that in `docker image inspect $image_name` under the .RootFS.Layers section.

Those layers are stored on the hard drive, and may be easily accessible depending on the storage driver being used. At least with overlay2, this is visible in the `docker image inspect` output under the .GraphDriver section.

Lastly, you can use `docker save` on any docker engine that has pulled a copy of the image from the registry to convert it back to a tar file that contains each layer as a tar file. So transferring an image by a registry does not eliminate this attack vector.

Answer (score 0):

[Docker Images](https://github.com/moby/moby/blob/master/image/spec/v1.2.md) are made up of 1 or more file system layers. Each command in a `Dockerfile` that modifies the file system will create a new file system layer. The sensitive files will remain in their layer after deletion from a higher layer (subsequent `Dockerfile` step).

You would need to export/import the built image to flatten the image layers and remove the sensitive files from an image built with your suggested steps.